# Why do we have 3 quantum colours?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle, confinement

I understand the need to invoke colour as another quantum state to explain the observation of uuu ddd and sss baryons. I just wanted to know if there was some other property which explains why we only came up with 3 colours. Is it just because you can only have a maximum of 3 quarks together and so only 3 were needed or some other reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The history is as you have described:

“Color quantum numbers ... were discovered as a consequence of the quark model classification, when it was appreciated that the spin S = ​3⁄2 baryon, the Δ++, required three up quarks with parallel spins and vanishing orbital angular momentum. Therefore, it could not have an antisymmetric wave function, (due to the Pauli exclusion principle), unless there were a hidden quantum number.”

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model#The_discovery_of_color

But the real reason why there are three and not more or fewer colors is that $SU(3)$ gauge theory appears to accurately describe the strong interaction between quarks.